# HTML button calls php function via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to call of PHP function via an html button using ajax so I do not have to refresh the page. The PHP function turns off an outlet on an IP power strip and has no return value, I have confirmed that the PHP function is not the problem as well. I am not sure if my ajax syntax is incorrect or if I require a GET method in my php code. Any help is appreciated!

```js
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("epdl-ps1.bucknell.edu", 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "\$A3 1 0\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="outlet1off">
 <a href="#" onsubmit="outlet1off()" id="outlet1off" class="outlet1off">Off</a>
     <script>
  function outlet1off(){

        $.ajax({
              url: "localhost/EPDL%20Control%20Page/outlet1off.php",
       type: "GET",
                     datatype:"html"
           });
  };
     
     </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your script at the top of the page? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: What is the difference having the script at the top or bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler code version. You need to use a click event instead of submit:

```
$('#outlet1off').click(function() {
    $.get('/EPDL%20Control%20Page/outlet1off.php');
});
```

You can add a `.done` or `.always` to the `$.get` if you need to deal with the returned data at all (error handling). see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: How would you tie ajax into this though?

Comment: `$.get` is a shorthand for `$.ajax`. `$.get` is sending a GET request to that URL. Since you said the PHP script returns no value, I didn't add a way to handle any returned data. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR for more information on handling returns from the GET request

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out (I feel dumb haha), the function worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `onclick` instead of `onsubmit`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="outlet1off()" id="outlet1off" class="outlet1off">Off</a>
```

**EDIT:**

Note also that you URL is not a valid one. Try:

```
url: "http://localhost/EPDL%20Control%20Page/outlet1off.php",
```

or

```
url: "/EPDL%20Control%20Page/outlet1off.php",
```

Comment: The OP is using jQuery, so why do inline JS at all?